# ListItemButton onclick wont fire on the first click when using my own component as children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I have issues understanding why this onclick cares what the children is and how it works

```
  <ListItemButton onClick={() => onClickResult(q)}>
       <Typography variant="body1">{highlighted}</Typography>
  </ListItemButton>
```

this examples where Typography from mui is beeing used works as aspected (first click triggers onClick)

but using allmost the same code but another children:

```
          <ListItemButton
            onClick={() => onClickResult(q)}
          >
            <HighlightText text={highlighted} />
          </ListItemButton>
```

where Highlighted is defined before the return():

```
  const HighlightText = ({ text }: { text: string }) => {
    const splitText = text.split('}');
    const hasHighlights = splitText.length > 1;
    if (!hasHighlights) {
      return <Typography variant="body1">{text}</Typography>;
    }
    return (
      <StyledHighlightText>
        <Typography variant="body1">{splitText[0].replace('{', '')}</Typography>
        <StyledHighlightTextBold variant="body1">
          {splitText[1]}
        </StyledHighlightTextBold>
      </StyledHighlightText>
    );
  };
```

and the on click:

```
  const onClickResult = (query: string) => {
    window.location.href = `${url}?q=${encodeURIComponent(
      query,
    )}&origin=PHRASE_SUGGEST`;
  };
```

Now i have to click twice before the onClick gets fired. I see absolutely no reason for it to take 2 clicks instead of 1 now in order to trigger click

Comment: what does onClickResult do ?

Comment: just changes window.location.href, i've updated the question with it

Comment: everything seems to be right, is that possible for you to make a codesandbox for it ?

Comment: little complicated, but I found a solution to it: create a method instead of a component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: create method instead of a component

```
      <ListItemButton
        onClick={() => onClickResult(q)}
      >
        {getHighlightText(highlighted)}
      </ListItemButton>
```

and

```
  const getHighlightText = (text: string) => {
    const splitText = text.split('}');
    const hasHighlights = splitText.length > 1;
    if (!hasHighlights) {
      return <Typography variant="body1">{text}</Typography>;
    }
    return (
      <StyledHighlightText>
        <Typography variant="body1">{splitText[0].replace('{', '')}</Typography>
        <StyledHighlightTextBold variant="body1">
          {splitText[1]}
        </StyledHighlightTextBold>
      </StyledHighlightText>
    );
  };
```

I still have no clue why using the component-way doesn't work